# How to create a hybrid data access layer with DTO and Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, dto

I want to create data access layer with a hybrid model with DTO for pull data and entities for insert/updates/deletes. I am creating repositories in entity framework for data access. I am not getting how can I create and use DTO to pull data. Please help me. If you have any resource/links please point me in that direction. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a seperate project which holds DTO object. It can be linked to data access layer and the Web API project. It helped in making a common DTO for data layer and api